# Would this question have been acceptable on this stack?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, specific-question

Or would [it](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/10247/are-actions-in-computer-games-bad-for-karma) have been closed for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question doesn't mention a specific school. It is to be answered from a Buddhist point of view. Here, you should add a philosophical school you want to focus on.

If that school is Buddhism, Hinduism, Christianity, ... it may fit better on their specific sites.